# Praying with pictures or money on the table

Tags: halacha, tefilla, avodah-zarah, tzedakah-charity, pictures

It [has been established](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/28395/3073) that one may not pray facing a picture.

1. May one pray by a table where pictures or money bills lie?
2. How about engraved images like coins?
3. If prohibited, how can the practice of praying in front of tzedaka money be justified?

Comment: During Pesukei d'Zimra, we push the money down in the rabbi's silver cup so no one can see the pictures while we are davening.

Comment: @Mike Is that joke (i.e. you are giving tzedakah, after which you cannot see the money) or is it serious description of behavior indicating a No to number 1.