# Having pictures in a room that is prayed in

Tags: halacha, tefilla, pictures

Is it assure to have pictures of people in a room where someone is praying, specifically on the eastern wall?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28394

Comment: Do you live west of Jerusalem?

Comment: I am pretty sure a certain hasidic group has photographs of their late spiritual leader on the walls of their synagogues and homes. Many Judaica stores sell paintings and photographs of great rabbis. Surely some are hung on the walls of homes and other locations where an individual or groups of people may congregate to pray.

Comment: @JJLL, if that is a reference to Chabad, I have never seen a picture in a synagogue. It is often in a Beis Medrash, though (which will be a place where regular tefillos happen, and has a sefer Torah, etc.), but never on the eastern wall, generally on the south wall.

Comment: You are correct Yishai. Would it make a difference in a synagogue where the ark does not face east?

Answer (score 3):

The [Aruch Hashulchan - O"C 90:28](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.90.28?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) says that it's best not to have any pictures in a room dedicated to praying.

**He is opposed to pictures of animals and birds - and all the more so people - in prayer locations.**

If one must decorate the prayer room the decorations should be higher than the height of an average person.

Especially problematic are pictures (below head-height) on the wall in the direction one prays to; if the wall one faces has pictures it's best to close one's eyes when praying.

He ends off saying that it's best that the wall one faces be empty and plain.

> הבגדים המצויירים, אף על פי שאינם בולטות – אין נכון להתפלל כנגדן, שלא יבלבלו אותו. ואם יקרה לו להתפלל כנגד בגד או כותל מצוייר – יעלים עיניו. וכן בכותלי בית הכנסת אסור לצייר ציורים כנגד פני המתפללים. אלא יהיו למעלה מקומת בני אדם, והיינו למעלה משלוש אמות שזהו קומת איש. וכן אין לצור ציורים בסידורים שמתפללין בהן, שלא תתבטל הכוונה. ודברים שמצוייר עליהם דברי תפילות – אפילו לישב עליהם בבית הכנסת אסור, ואפילו בביתו יתרחק את עצמו מהם. ובכלל נכון לבטל כל הציורים של חיות ועופות, וכל שכן ציורי אדם, שעושים על כותלי בתי כנסיות. **ובכלל יש להתרחק מכל הציורים גם בבית**. ואמת שהתפילה היותר נאותה שתהיה כותל חלקה, ולא יהיה כנגדו שום דבר גדול וקטן. ומכבדין בפתח בית הכנסת שהגדול יכנס תחילה (ברכות מז א).‏

The [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 18:8](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.18.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) adds that one may not pray facing a mirror, even if one closes one's eyes.

> וְכֵן לֹא יִתְפַּלֵּל כְּנֶגֶד אֵיזֶה צִיּוּר, וְאִם יִקְרֶה לוֹ לְהִתְפַּלֵּל כְּנֶגֶד בֶּגֶד, אוֹ כּוֹתֶל מְצֻיָּר יִסְגֹּר עֵינָיו, וּכְנֶגֶד מַרְאֶה אָסוּר לְהִתְפַּלֵּל, אֲפִלּוּ בְּעֵינַיִם סְגוּרוֹת.‏