# Is it permitted to face a Chanukiah when davenning?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, chanuka

[Rabbi Yitzchok in the Gemoro Bovo Basro 25b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=25b&format=text) advises
אמר רבי יצחק הרוצה שיחכים ידרים ושיעשיר יצפין וסימניך שלחן בצפון ומנורה בדרום 
Someone who wants to become wise should turn to the south (when davenning) and who wishes to become rich should turn to the north and the way to remember it is that the Shulchan (Table, symbol of wealth) is towards the north and the Menora (symbol of wisdom) is towards the south.

The Rema quotes this is [O Ch 94 (2)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=252&hilite=) where the Mishna Berura {12} explains that one should turn his face to the south while keeping his body facing to Eretz Yisroel.

My question is whether on Chanukah when we have a lit Chanukiah in the south, is it still permitted to  turn his face in that direction? Might it be thought that a person is davenning to the Chanukiah? (The question seems more intense when it is lit but is there even when it is not lit.)

Related to (lehavdil) [Davening in front of a picture of 'Avodah Zarah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28394/davening-in-front-of-a-picture-of-avodah-zarah) .

Comment: Similarly, if the Chanukiah is in the east and you are just praying east or it's in the north and you live south of Jerusalem. I don't know why you need to bring in your first two paragraphs.

Comment: @DoubleAA the _m'nora_ is on the south side of a synagogue on _Chanuka_, was the point, I guess. But of course any old candelabrum might be anywhere around someone praying, as can a tire pump or moccasin: I'm not sure what's special about a _m'nora_.