# What is considered a picture for not davening in front of it

Tags: halacha-theory, chazzan-prayer-leader

I heard that you can't daven in front of a picture

What does this included?

1. A mogen Dovid?
2. A flag of israel?
3. A lion?
4. What if it is part of the paroiches or Aron kodesh
   ....

Similar [Davening in front of a picture of 'Avodah Zarah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28394)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64379

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Ramma in siman 90 siff 23 explains the reason not to pray in front of pictures is because it distracts one from concentrating.

This is the same reasoning The Mishna Berurah there uses to explain the Mechaber.

So in fact any picture that distracts, such as one found on clothing as the Mechaber mentioned, are problematic.

The Mishna Berurah also points out that praying in front of a mirror is problematic both because it looks like one is praying to the reflection, and because it is distracting.

Comment: I want to add that it seems that praying to a reflection is a form of avodo zara see [yd 11.3](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.11.3)