# Shushan Purim and my wall art

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

If I have a picture of Jerusalem on my wall, do I celebrate Shushan Purim because I can see Yerushalayim all the time?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Cute. But this would be a much stronger (funnier) question if you'd quote (or paraphrase) and cite a source indicating that those who can see Jerusalem celebrate on the 15th. Questions should be fully fleshed-out here on Mi Yodeya, so everyone can benefit. Welcome! I recommend our [tour].

Comment: Welcome, mendy! Nice question. You should consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Comment: maybe related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59420/759

Answer (score 1):

Chabad has a [footnote](http://www.chabad.org/holidays/purim/article_cdo/aid/645278/jewish/Shushan-Purim.htm)

> Purim is also observed on the 15th in all locales that are adjacent to
>   a walled city—such as all the Jerusalem neighborhoods that are outside
>   the walled old city.

Since you would be living outside the current boundaries of Yerushalaim, then you would still be required to observe the 14th of Adar. However, since you are that close, you would be allowed to enter the picture and go to a shul there to hear the megilla and celebrate with the inhabitants of Yerushalaim. It would be like someone living outside the current boundaries of Yerushalaim, but who can travel into the current boundaries to join the celebration.

Comment: "Purim is also observed on the 15th in all locales that are adjacent to a walled city" This is technically true, but misses half the story whereby it also observed in locales that can see the city even if far away. (סמוך ונראה as the Gemara calls it) The details of course get complicated.